# What is the most obvious jakarta version of javax.servlet:jstl?

Tags: tomcat, jstl

What is the jakarta version of

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version> 
    </dependency>
```

?
I found that the following works:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is the glassfish dependency the most obvious solution?